# Error using cases (memisc)

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have this data example:

`W1$age <- c(3,2,4,1,1,3,4,NA,2,NA)`

I want to create a column in which:

- 1 is replaced by 0
- 2,3,4 are replaced by 1
- everything else is NA

I have this code:

```
library(memisc)
W1$age2 =  cases( 
  "0"= W1$age == 1,
  "1" = W1$age == 2 | W1$age == 3 | W1$age == 4,
  "NA" = W1$age != c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4")
  )
```

it gives me this error (I googled it but I didn't find it):

```
Error in if (any(done == 0) && any(done > 1)) msg("conditions are neither exhaustive nor mutually exclusive") else if (any(done ==  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In W1$age != c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4") :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I hope you can help me either to fix it with some alternatives,
thanks a lot!

Comment: The old code is not working, I get this error `Error in if (any(done == 0) && any(done > 1)) msg("conditions are neither exhaustive nor mutually exclusive") else if (any(done ==  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `base`, you could do:

```
x<- c(3,2,4,1,1,3,4,NA,2,NA)
x[x==1]<-0 #for x equal 1 convert to 0
x[(x==2|x==3|x==4)]<-1 #for x equal to 2,3, or 4 convert to 1
x[(!x %in% c(0:4))]<-NA #if x is not equal to 0 - 4 convert to NA
```

Comment: It works @User7598 !  `W1$age[W1$age=="1"]<- 0
W1$age[(W1$age=="2"|W1$age=="3"|W1$age=="4")]<-1` Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, that will work... I added the last line in case you have values outside of 0 - 4 in your vector. If you don't, then what you did will work.